# Android - Correctly position views

Tags: android

In My android I want :--
here "Or" is a text view..this textview is surrounded by circle view and a vertical line is passing by the circle..

Here is my code:--

**This code is for textview with rounded circle**

**round.xml** in drawable folder:--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke android:color="#22ff55" android:width="3dip"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp" />

    <size
        android:height="60dp"
        android:width="60dp" />

</shape>
```

and in my **layout**

I have textviews as:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_tv"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="or"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

and this code for vertical line:--

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000FF" />
```

So I have textview with rounded Circle and a verticle line..

But my problem is how can I join this two codes???
or If my concept is wrong..How can I achieve that thing??????suggest me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to make the circle and line a .png image, and make it the background for a TextView with the text.

Also, you should avoid using views for dividers (like that line) if at all possible.  Views are fairly heavyweight to create and layout all the time.  If you have a complex app they'll come back to bite you in performance issues.

Comment: What Should be the standard size,height and weight of the ".png"(what you have suggested)??

Answer (score 0):

As you have done this you can take the Textview and view inside the FrameLayout. FrameLayout will help you show one control over the other

```
<FrameLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
//Put here
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` as the container for all the above views and use it to properly position all the views.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="..."
  android:layout_height="...">

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

 <Button
   android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

  <View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#FF0000FF" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_tv"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="or"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In this code, background of the "circle textview" the line view is also showing..

Comment: I don't understand... you see the line behind the textview with the background drawable set to the shape you defined. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes,I dont want this line..How can I hide this?

Comment: just remove the view with the 1dp width.